# How would I import a file from an input()

Tags: python, input, import

I am writing a small program that you can add different plugins to the app.

(Not Full) Code:

```
external_python_script = input('Full Filename: ')
import external_python_script
```

Say, if the input was mytestfile.py and its contents were just

```
print('Hello World!')
```

then it should print to the console when i run the main program.

I get a syntax error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/censored/Desktop/pyproject/1/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    import external_python_script
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'external_python_script'
```

This is quite annoying because the file IS in the same directory, and when i do `import another_file_in_directory` it works.

Thanks for any help/feedback.

Comment: The error message shows something very different than the "snipped of code". Note though that ``import`` is for modules, not files – which of the two do you want to work with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry that was a different program. I fixed it now so it matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import does not work with variables. You will need to use a different library to import via `input()` see `importlib`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

You could accomplish it with something like this:

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(input('Full Filename: '))
```

Though with the above code an error might occur due to the user entering the files extension along with the name.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b.py'; 'b' is not a package

A workaround to this is provided below where we just remove the extension.

```
import importlib
importlib.import_module(input('Full Filename: ').split('.')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, although there is an error when I put the FULL filename, but I fixed this by removing the extension.

Comment: I have edited the post to fix this error @msteviee

Comment: A filename might include a range of other characters that are not valid – directory separators or just illegal module characters such as ``-``. Just asking for a module/package name would be more straightforward.